# how to get all individual matches from a regex in perl?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl

I have this:

```
my %names = qw (hanibal lecter Harry Potter INDIANA JONES Sarah connor scarlet O'Hara JAMES Bond);
```

or this:

```
my $scalar_string = "hanibal lecter Harry Potter INDIANA JONES Sarah connor scarlet O'Hara JAMES Bond";
```

How to get all first and last name use `/[\w']+\ [\w']+/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with a hash, just use [keys](http://p3rl.org/keys) and [values](http://p3rl.org/values) to extract the first names and last names. To extract the names from a string, just add capture groups and `/g` to find all the matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my %names = qw (hanibal lecter Harry Potter INDIANA JONES Sarah connor scarlet O'Hara JAMES Bond);

say join ' ', 'First names:', keys %names;
say join ' ', 'Last names:', values %names;

my $scalar_string = "hanibal lecter Harry Potter INDIANA JONES Sarah connor scarlet O'Hara JAMES Bond";

my (@first_names, @last_names);
while ($scalar_string =~ /([\w']+) ([\w']+)/g) {
    push @first_names, $1;
    push @last_names, $2;
}
say join ' ', 'First names:', @first_names;
say join ' ', 'Last names:', @last_names;
```